# Java TreePath.equals() trouble

Tags: java, swing, outline

I'm having trouble getting an Outline control (alternative TreeTable) to work with a tree of data objects, due to the method that TreePath uses to identify data nodes.

The key problem is that TreePath's equals() method uses the data nodes' equals() method to identify that two node objects are the same ones in the data tree.  TreeModel.java even comments on this problem:

"Some implementations may assume that if two TreePaths are equal [as determined by equals()], they identify the same node. If this condition is not met, painting problems and other oddities may result." Example data:

- A

  - B

    - C
    - D
  - B

    - E
    - F
  - H
  - K

Here, the two "B" nodes might, as individual nodes, be considered to have equal values (hence equals() returns true), but they certainly do not represent the same nodes in the tree.

OK, so if the source data objects have implemented equals() to indicate equal *value considering just the node itself*, this breaks TreePath if more than one node of the same value appears under a particular parent. In that case, Outline is unable to expand/collapse the correct one of the same-value nodes.

This problem would be solved if TreePath.equals() used "==" instead of data objects' equals() methods. However, since the stock TreePath is closely wired into TreeModel etc etc, it's not obvious how to go about repairing this behavior without a lot of disruption.

Is there some graceful way to get the right effect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I think that the problem comes from the way you are implementing `equals()` in your `TreeNode`'s. Two `TreeNode`'s, in your case, should be considered equals if they represent the same visual nodes. Two `TreeNode`'s can represent the same model object (for example Model Object B) but remain different nodes..

Here is a simple demo based on DefaultMutableTreeNode (`equals()` uses the `Object.equals(Object)` default implementation `==`). Every 2 seconds it toggles selection from node B1 to B2:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.ToolTipManager;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

public class TestTreeNodes {

    public static class SomeModelNode {
        private String value;

        public SomeModelNode(String value) {
            super();
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

    }

    public class MyTreeCellRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean sel, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row,
                boolean hasFocus) {
            Component cell = super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
            if (value instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode) {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode treeNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) value;
                if (treeNode.getUserObject() instanceof SomeModelNode) {
                    setText(((SomeModelNode) treeNode.getUserObject()).getValue());
                }
            }
            return cell;
        }
    }

    private JFrame f;
    private JTree tree;
    private DefaultMutableTreeNode nodeA;
    private DefaultMutableTreeNode nodeB1;
    private DefaultMutableTreeNode nodeB2;
    private DefaultMutableTreeNode nodeC;
    private DefaultMutableTreeNode nodeD;
    private DefaultMutableTreeNode nodeE;
    private DefaultMutableTreeNode nodeF;
    private DefaultMutableTreeNode nodeH;
    private DefaultMutableTreeNode nodeK;

    private boolean showingB1 = false;

    protected void initUI() {
        tree = new JTree(getModel());
        for (int i = 0; i < tree.getRowCount(); i++) {
            tree.expandRow(i);
        }
        ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().registerComponent(tree);
        tree.setCellRenderer(new MyTreeCellRenderer());
        f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.add(new JScrollPane(tree));
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
        Timer t = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!showingB1) {
                    tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionPath(getPathForNode(nodeB1));
                } else {
                    tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionPath(getPathForNode(nodeB2));
                }
                showingB1 = !showingB1;
            }
        });
        t.start();

    }

    private TreePath getPathForNode(TreeNode node) {
        List<TreeNode> nodes = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();
        TreeNode current = node;
        while (current != null) {
            nodes.add(current);
            current = current.getParent();
        }
        Collections.reverse(nodes);
        return new TreePath(nodes.toArray(new Object[nodes.size()]));
    }

    private TreeModel getModel() {
        SomeModelNode a = new SomeModelNode("A");
        SomeModelNode b = new SomeModelNode("B");
        SomeModelNode c = new SomeModelNode("C");
        SomeModelNode d = new SomeModelNode("D");
        SomeModelNode e = new SomeModelNode("E");
        SomeModelNode f = new SomeModelNode("F");
        SomeModelNode h = new SomeModelNode("H");
        SomeModelNode k = new SomeModelNode("K");
        nodeA = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(a);
        nodeB1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(b);
        nodeB2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(b);
        nodeC = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(c);
        nodeD = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(d);
        nodeE = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(e);
        nodeF = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(f);
        nodeH = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(h);
        nodeK = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(k);
        // Children of A
        nodeA.add(nodeB1);
        nodeA.add(nodeB2);
        nodeA.add(nodeH);
        nodeA.add(nodeK);
        // Children of B1
        nodeB1.add(nodeC);
        nodeB1.add(nodeD);
        // Children of B2
        nodeB2.add(nodeE);
        nodeB2.add(nodeF);
        DefaultTreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(nodeA);
        return model;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestTreeNodes().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I agree that if the data node (TreeNode as you call it) uses the default Object.equals() implementation (which uses ==), then all is well. However, overriden equals() is not in general required to be that strict, on the basis that it could be conveying equal-in-value, rather than same-object. 
In the case at hand, I don't have control over the data node's implementation of equals().  To make progress on the data side, at the moment it seems like I'd have to construct a whole new tree (with favorably-implemented equals(), etc etc.

Comment: Ah, and I now see your point about equals() should be true _only_ for same visual node (ie: child 5 of a particular parent, for example), and not for the same underlying data node referenced from somewhere else in the tree view.  That's a case different from the one I was pursuing (say child 3 and child 5 of same parent having same "value"), but also important.

Comment: @gwideman Without seeing how your code has been written, it is a bit hard to give proper advice. A mistake I often see is that the model directly implements `javax.swing.tree.TreeNode` which leads to the behaviour you are describing. Eventually, it all comes down to how `javax.swing.tree.TreeNode.equals(Object)` is implemented. If for two different visual position it returns `true` then you should expect oddities, otherwise the result is totally predictable and stable.

Comment: Agreed -- as currently designed, TreeModel and other code depends on TreePath.equals(), which in turn depends on the data node's equals(). (By the way, my data tree is from 3rd party library, and not based on j.s.t.TreeNode). That seems like an incorrect dependency -- it seems to me that the test for data node equality for purposes of visual tree should be implemented in the user-supplied TreeModel implementation, to properly separate visual tree from data tree. Lack of that separation is what my question is trying to get an answer to :-).

Comment: @gwideman I am not sure I understand what you mean, and once again, may I insist that without seeing your code, it is really hard to help you. Anyway, you can always separate the visual TreeModel (TreeModel/TreeNode implementations) from your actual model (which can possibly be a tree or some kind of acyclic diagram). If you look at my example again, the underlying model (here a simple class called `SomeModelNode`) is completely separated from the TreeModel (which relies on DefaultTreeModel and DefaultMutableTreeNode). It would really help if you could post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry for no SSCCCE, my case depends on 3rd party library. You understand the issue anyway. Your solution is basically to wrap the data nodes in TreePath-friendly DefaultMutableTreeNode(), and then build a  tree from them (duplicating the structure of the underlying data tree, in my case). I realize this is a way to proceed, but this requires keeping the duplicate tree in sync with the underlying tree, which considerably increases complexity. But, c'est la vie, I guess.

Comment: I think I'll declare this at "the answer" for now. Partially because it's at least "an" answer (albeit not simple as hoped), and partially because, prompted by my questioning, the 3rd party library has been revised so that data node equals() now distinguishes child nodes from one another.  I'm still of the opinion that this node equals() business is a matter that should be part of TreeModel's responsibility... after all, surely the point of TreeModel is to be the interface to external data and structure, not requiring a copy of the external data and structure.  Thanks!